# Success function in .ajax() doesn't execute

Tags: json, jquery

When I debug using Firebug I see the control jumping to error section after hitting success. I am unable to find out what is going wrong. Can some body please point out what is wrong with this code.

```
$(function(){     
     $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "service/MyService.asmx/GetAsgInfo",
                data: "{id: " + parseInt($('#AsgId').val()) + "}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (msg) {
                   // var s = eval('(' + msg.d + ')');
                         alert(msg.d[0].SubmittedCount);
                        },
                error: function (e) {
                    alert("error : " + e);
                }
            });
});
```

POST :

```
{id: 5301}
```

RESPONSE :

```
       {"d":[{"__type":"Proxies.AFARServiceRef.AssignmentInfo","ExtensionData":
    {},"AssignDate":"\/Date(1319526000000)\/","AssignFileName":null,"ClaimId":"MH001025","ClaimantName":"Deborah C Plaid","FirstContactDate":"\/Date(1319526000000)\/","FirstContactTime":
{"Ticks":420000000000,"Days":0,"Hours":11,"Milliseconds":0,"Minutes":40,"Seconds":0,"TotalDays":
0.4861111111111111,"TotalHours":11.666666666666666,"TotalMilliseconds":42000000,"TotalMinutes":700,"TotalSeconds":42000},"Id":5301,"InspectionDate":"\/Date(1319612400000)\/","StatusId":1,
"SubmittedCount":4,"UploadedCount":14}]}
```

Comment: Check the status code returned by MyService.asmx

Comment: Is this exactly how you get the response? There should not be a line break after `"TotalMinutes":7`, this will generate an error (it's not valid JSON).

Comment: @MichaelMior the Status code under HTML tab (Firebug) says 302 Found

Comment: @FelixKling I guess by mistake I entered a line break. The response is a valid JSON object.

Comment: ran the response for you in jslint and it doesn't complain about any JSON errors.

Comment: I've had 302 redirects break AJAX before; but I can't say for sure this is the problem as I don't fully recall the context. Also: is it necessary to explicitly declare a contentType? I can't say I've ever had the need.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the success and error functions, try using complete:

```
complete: function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
  alert(textStatus);
}
```

Comment: The textSTatus contains the string "Success". how should continue further to fetch the data.

Comment: Could do this just as a test, but I don't recommend it for production. They want code that acts on the response when successful, and catch the error if not. The complete parameter is more useful for "no matter what, run this" code. If they use complete, they will have to write a way to handle errors.

Comment: @GregPettit, BumbleBee is dealing with the problem referred to in this [ticket](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/9399). I recommended 'complete' (or the new 'always') because it's a catch all, including server side errors. If the alert says "success" then there must be a problem with the response not being interpreted as JSON.

Comment: @BumbleBee, are you familiar with using breakpoints? Have you tried placing a breakpoint on the "alert(msg.d[0].SubmittedCount);" line, and checking the 'msg' variable's value? I suspect it may be a string and not an object.

Comment: @CalebGray I'm obviously not getting the same information from the ticket as you. ;-) I see now that they're being deprecated (news to me, thank you for that!!), but I don't see the situation in which they fail, and I DO see that the parameters will start off aliased. It also states that 'complete' is a trickier scenario for deprecation.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with handling json, and it turns out I wasn't setting the content-type properly on the server side.  Even valid json sometimes causes weird errors when it is in a response labeled as "text/plain" or even "text/json".  Make sure your content type is right.